# jQuery submitHandler complains about loading spinner

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am placing my spinner inside my submitHandler, immediately following my validate messages...I only want it active during the ajaxSubmit, so it seems natural to put it on top before the JSON. But jQuery complains **"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( **. I tried it with a comma at the end instead of a semi, and eithier way doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
 submitHandler: function(form) {
    $("#registerform").ajaxSubmit({
    >>>>>>  $('#loadingDiv').show().html('<img src="images/loading.gif">');
                        url: 'action.php',
                        type: 'post',
                        success: function(resp) {
                            $('#loadingDiv').hide("fast");
                            $(".formbox").hide();
                            $(".thankyou").fadeIn("slow");
                            console.log('success');
                        },
                        fail: function(resp) {
                            $('#loadingDiv').hide("fast");
                            console.log('fail' + resp);
                            $("#registerform").css("border", "1px solid red");
                        }
                    });
                }

        });
```

Comment: Put that above the `ajaxSubmit` handle above, you're inside the object literal definition you can't just put code to execute there.

Comment: I will try that...if I can ever get my cache refreshed...

Comment: @Benjamin G.  Yes, this worked. If you make it an answer I will select it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help. Seems like other answers were added, there is no point to add a duplicate answer now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put code like this inside a JSON object:

```
$('#loadingDiv').show().html('<img src="images/loading.gif">');
```

Try moving this up a line so that it's before the call to `ajaxSubmit`.

I take your point about it feeling natural, but you're actually mixing the code used to send the AJAX request with code that manipulates your DOM.  Given that your success and failure handler functions both hide the "loading" image when invoked, you should still see the desired effect.

Comment: I don't see any JSON objects in the question, do you?

Comment: Both this answer and the comment from Ben were correct. I placed my loadingDiv line before the call to ajaxSubmit. Thank you to those who answered.

Comment: @Benjamin Sorry if it's not the correct terminology, but you know I mean the object passed to `ajaxSubmit`!

Comment: Not an object...By JSON, I just meant the syntax of the ajaxSubmit function.

Comment: @ATG It's not the correct terminology. JSON is a data serialization format used to pass data around (like XML). What the code above has is a JavaScript object literal. JSON objects and JavaScript objects are different beasts but might look the same for simple data. For example - JSON objects may not contain functions, and all attributes must be double quoted. You can see the JSON representation of a JavaScript object by typing `JSON.stringify(myObject)` also - http://json.org describes the JSON grammar :)

Comment: @Benjamin Sorry, my mistake.  Cheers for the clarification, though!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    $("#registerform").ajaxSubmit({
                        url: 'action.php',
                        type: 'post',
                        success: function(resp) {
                            $('#loadingDiv').hide("fast");
                            $(".formbox").hide();
                            $(".thankyou").fadeIn("slow");
                            console.log('success');
                        },
                        fail: function(resp) {
                            $('#loadingDiv').hide("fast");
                            console.log('fail' + resp);
                            $("#registerform").css("border", "1px solid red");
                        },
                        beforeSubmit: function(arr, $form, options) { 
                            $('#loadingDiv').show().html('<img src="images/loading.gif">');
                        }
                    });
                }

        });
```

you need that beforeSubmit function

Comment: Actually, this is probably the best idea if you're using the jQuery form plugin.  Do remember the comma after the "fail" function, though. `;-)`